# Textures / GameObjects disappear on right camera when leaving left camera

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I'm trying to create a VR app for iOS using Unity and the Google Cardboard SDK.

Here is a short video about it:
https://streamable.com/vql157

I've repeated the steps from https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart?authuser=2 a hundred times, created several projects and just don't know where this error comes from.

When I create a new Unity project and only import the Google Cardboard Sample Scene, the error also occurs. (For the sphere game object)

Has anyone already experienced this or knows how to work around this problem?

Comment: also on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/k4jxca/im_trying_to_create_a_vrapp_for_ios_using_unity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a solution to work around the problem, so I decided to do without VR plugins completely, i.e. no XR management plugin and no G-Cardboard XR plugin.

My solution:
I have created two independent cameras, which are combined by the father object and thus form the main camera. Then I assigned a script to the parent object of the main camera, which reads the gyroscope data from my iPhone and thus adjusts the rotation of the camera.